# Dart / flutter: String data from initState can't be passed via setState

Tags: dart, flutter

Yesterday I made a simple widget that fetches data to display some basic info, but I noticed that when I pop back to the list, the data is usually absent and I only get my error texts.

I figured this is due to these widgets originally being stateless, so I'm trying to convert them to stateful in order to reload the data when the page is loaded.

This is how I gather the data for my widget:

```
class BasicDogWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  String URL;

  BasicDogWidget(this.URL);

  @override
  createState() => new BasicDogWidgetState(URL);
}

class BasicDogWidgetState extends State<BasicDogWidget> {
  String URL;
  BasicDogWidgetState(this.URL);

  var result;
  var imageLink;
  var dogName;
  var dogType;
  var dogColor;
  var dogGender;
  var dogAge;

  @override
  initState() {
    fetchImageLink(URL).then((result) {
      setState(imageLink = result);
    });

    fetchDogInfo(URL, 'datas-nev').then((result) {
      setState(dogName = result);
    });

    fetchDogInfo(URL, 'datas-tipus').then((result) {
      setState(dogType = result);
    });

    fetchDogInfo(URL, 'datas-szin').then((result) {
      setState(dogColor = result);
    });

    fetchDogInfo(URL, 'datas-nem').then((result) {
      setState(dogGender = result);
    });

    fetchDogInfo(URL, 'datas-kor').then((result) {
      setState(dogAge = result);
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (imageLink == null) {
      return new Container();
    }

    if (dogName == null) {
      return new Container();
    }

    if (dogType == null) {
      return new Container();
    }

    if (dogColor == null) {
      return new Container();
    }

    if (dogGender == null) {
      return new Container();
    }

    if (dogAge == null) {
      return new Container();
    }

    return buildBasicWidget(
        imageLink, dogName, dogType, dogColor, dogGender, dogAge, URL);
  }
}
```

However, it seems that the data collected by `fetchDogInfo` can't be passed in the `setState` method as it is a string.

```
E/flutter (12296): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (12296): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'VoidCallback' of 'fn' where
E/flutter (12296):   String is from dart:core
E/flutter (12296): 
E/flutter (12296): #0      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1086)
E/flutter (12296): #1      BasicDogWidgetState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:osszefogasaszanhuzokert/dog.dart:230)
```

Is there any way this issue can be bypassed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing async code

```
fetchImageLink(URL).then((result) {
```

which means `fetchImageLink(URL)` will eventually return a value and then `then(...)` is executed, but this call is async, which means it's added to the event queue for later execution and the code synchronically continues to execute until the end of `initState` and then `build` until this sync code is run to its completion, then the next "task" from the event queue is executed, which might be the `then(...)` part from your `fetchImageLink()` call if it already completed.

That shouldn't be a problem though.
You could just check if the value is available

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(imageLink == null) {
      return new Container(); // dummy widget until there is something real to render
    }

    ... // your other build code
```

Comment: Yes, I found out that I forgot about the dummy data for the loading part. I made some edits to the code (now it can be seen above), and found out that the problem is that initState can't pass the returned string data via setState, so even though the data is collected, it is never passed and an exception is thrown which causes a crash. Can I somehow pass the string in the setState method?

Comment: I did and understand the mechanics that are happening in the background. I also updated the dummy container part according to your suggestion (see the code above), and now I get an empty scaffold with the titleBar properly constructed, but when the setState method returns the value, I get the Exception you can see above.

Comment: `setState` expects a function, not a value `setState(dogName = result);` should be `setState(() => dogName = result);`

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you could make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter have [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) class. It provides a widget that does all the heavy lifting to support asynchronous Future objects. The nice thing about FutureBuilder is that is can be added directly to the widget tree, and based off the current status of the connection, the relevant UI can be displayed to indicate progress, a result or an error.

Example:

```
class JokePageState extends State<JokePage> {
  Future<String> response;

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    response = http.read(dadJokeApi, headers: httpHeaders);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new FutureBuilder<String>(
          future: response,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return const Icon(Icons.sync_problem);
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
              case ConnectionState.active:
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              case ConnectionState.done:
                final decoded = json.decode(snapshot.data);
                if (decoded['status'] == 200) {
                  return new Text(decoded['joke']);
                } else {
                  return const Icon(Icons.error);
                }
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I actually use the FutureBuilder elsewhere in my app, but for this particular page I want to force the redrawing of the widgets, which needs SatefulWidget (from what I understand) to be executed on page load, and there the initState method can do the work (and seems a bit cleaner code-wise).